# Why does Audrey Hepburn's character ask for 50 dollars from her admirers every time she goes to "the powder room"?

Tags: plot-explanation, breakfast-at-tiffanys

Why does Audrey Hepburn's character in *Breakfast at Tiffany's* ask for 50 dollars from her admirers every time she goes to "the powder room"? It seems like a gold digger, master level but was that some weird standard at the time?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Holly was simply fleecing the men for their cash, *ostensibly to pay the toilet-room attendant* but in reality she was pocketing the money and using it to pay her rent and living expenses

In the [source novella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakfast_at_Tiffany%27s_(novella)) we get this exchange;

> *"I wasn't impressed by the honorarium either; you can do as well as that on tips to the powder room: any gent with the slightest chic will give you fifty for the girl's john, and I always ask for cab fare too; that's another fifty.*".

Note that Holly **isn't** a prostitute (she rarely sleeps with her dates) so much as a semi-professional "*good time girl*", making the men pay for her company under the pretence of being on a real date.

---

Truman Capote spoke about Holly in a Playboy article from 1968

> **Playboy:** *Would you elaborate on your comment that Holly was the prototype of today's liberated female and representative of a "whole breed of girls who live off men but are not prostitutes. They're our version of the geisha girl..."?*
>
> **Capote:** *Holly Golightly was not precisely a call girl. She had no job, but accompanied expense-account men to the best restaurants and night clubs, with the understanding that her escort was obligated to give her some sort of gift, perhaps jewelry or a check ... if she felt like it, she might take her escort home for the night. So these girls are the authentic American geishas, and they're much more prevalent now than in 1943 or 1944, which was Holly's era*

Comment: Wow. What really worries me is that we glorify the movie and Audrey Hepburn. Watching the movie, I got an impression that taking money from men without boundaries is completely OK. How come there is no criticism of this? In the end of the movie though, Holly ends up with a man on love terms. Does movie than tell us that Holly was wrong in the beginning?

Comment: @Haris - The reality is that these aren't wealthy men, they're businessmen defrauding their companies and taking out "clients". Nobody in these films is a hero.

Comment: What men and what clients are you talking about?

Comment: Note that the movie is a significantly cleaned-up version of the novel, much to Capote's dismay.

Comment: @Haris - The men she was taking out were largely using their business expense accounts to pay for the drinks and food on the pretext of taking clients out.

Comment: @Haris: “I got an impression that taking money from men without boundaries is completely OK. How come there is no criticism of this?” If everyone consents, where’s the harm?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Well, technically the guys she was dating were committing expenses fraud, harming the companies they work for and damaging the wider economy. I think we can also assume that many of her "dates" were married which means that she's knowingly harming their relationships. On top of that, she's taking money under false pretenses. Although it's a minor thing, that's also a form of fraud.

Comment: @Haris If Capote intended for Holly to be a modern American version of Geishas, then I'd like to note that in Japanese culture Geishas were, and still are, very highly respected. Not to the point of nobles but certainly on par with or even slightly higher than gentry (businessmen, landowners etc). So it makes sense that the movie gives a sense of "nothing wrong" about what she does.

Comment: @Richard: “harming the companies they work for and damaging the wider economy” — I’d query the second part. The New York nighttime economy is probably doing quite well out of her activities, and I’m sure her landlord appreciates her rent money. (Plus that nice restaurant Tiffany’s gets some of the cash when she breakfasts there.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - As someone who's economically inactive, her net contribution to the economy is minimal. She produces nothing whilst consuming considerable resources that would be far more efficiently spent by the money's original owner. I guess her occupation broadly falls under the heading of "services" but since most of her dates end in disappointment, it's not really that useful.

Comment: @Richard: She produces *nothing*?? She makes the party happen! The economy isn’t just about steel and automobiles, you know. It’s about people.

Comment: @pauld.waite - She's the human equivalent of a '[clip joint](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clip_joint)'

Comment: Yes, but note that the film (which concerns this site) is different from the book, and what may be true for one is not necessarily true for the other. The characters and plot of the film have been substantially changed. In other words the source novella does not dictate the interpretation of the film, since the filmmakers put their own vision on the film. They are two related but distinct works of art. Although I did upvote the answer.

Answer (score 7):

It's been a number of years since I last watched this, but I think it was something like this:

Holly Golightly is an aspirational character (i.e. she is trying to appear more than she is).  At that time, rest rooms were largely staffed (in good restaurants/tiffanys etc), and as part of using it someone like Holly would be expected to leave a tip.

Being poor, Holly would "borrow" a $50 bill from her date (a largish sum at that point), then when leaving she would be able to say to the attendant "Sorry, that's all I have", avoiding paying the tip, without looking cheap (and keeping up the image of being well off).  You can draw your own conclusions about what happened to the $50 afterwards.

Comment: Haha wow Crazy. But would she give her date the money back afterwards?

Comment: Well see Richard's answer, probably not.

Comment: An interesting theory however the book quotes and interview with the author show that this just isn't correct.

Comment: @Richard - As much as I like your answer, the question is why she asked the date for $50 for the toilet.  I'm sure she was fleecing the date by keeping the money, but the reason for getting money for the toilet was due to a tip being expected.

Comment: That was the *pretext*, certainly. But then she already said that in the film.

Comment: Yes but it was also the question ;)

Comment: Look, everybody involved knew what the $50 was for. This was just a "polite" way to pay for her services without being explicit about it. This whole "she was scamming the bathroom attendants out of a tip" is just nonsense, since in her profession she needs to be on good terms with employees of the clubs etc. she "does business in".

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of like Chris Elliott character in Groundhog Day in which he pretends to leave a big tip to impress or appease his lady friend (want-to-be-date) only to keep the money as she's turned her head, walking away.  In fact, many if not most of the men are looked down to as pathetic characters who we laugh at including the star, Bill Murray, who we 'all' love and adore.  No wonder we find ourselves in a most challenging situation in this country including politics where American woman want to be rich, socially respected, dominate over others and in control of their lives and others.  But that's not politically correct to say or even to understand, just like Audrey Hepburn's character in Breakfast at Tiffany's.  We like living a lie to others and ourselves especially in a heavily religious infused country, and the book story gets watered down in this country but probably not elsewhere.